# MySQL inconsistently altering name of indexes associated with foreign keys on InnoDB tables

Tags: mysql, sql, indexing, foreign-keys, innodb

I seem to have encountered an inconsistency in the way an `ALTER TABLE` statement behaves when dropping and adding a foreign key. Sometimes the associated index will be renamed and other times it isn't. I have identified the situations under which this occurs:

---

**APPROACH #1**

A simple `person` table with an auto-incrementing primary key `id` and a foreign key column to itself `self_id`. Note: the behaviour would be the same for two separate tables, I have used one table to simplify the example.

```
CREATE TABLE `person` (
  `id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `self_id` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
  KEY `self_id_fk` (`self_id`),
  CONSTRAINT `self_id_fk` FOREIGN KEY (`self_id`) REFERENCES `person` (`id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;
```

Next I rename the foreign key by dropping the existing one and then adding a new one. This is done in a single statement but the behaviour is the same if split into multiple `ALTER TABLE` statements.

```
ALTER TABLE `person`
  DROP FOREIGN KEY `self_id_fk`,
  ADD CONSTRAINT `a_new_fk_name` FOREIGN KEY (`self_id`) REFERENCES `person` (`id`);
```

After this statement the table is as follows:

```
CREATE TABLE `person` (
  `id` int(11) unsigned NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `self_id` int(11) unsigned DEFAULT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
  KEY `self_id_fk` (`self_id`),
  CONSTRAINT `a_new_fk_name` FOREIGN KEY (`self_id`) REFERENCES `person` (`id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;
```

Notice that the foreign key has been renamed but the index has not.

---

**APPROACH #2**

An alternative way of doing this would be to first create the table without any foreign keys or indexes:

```
CREATE TABLE `person` (
  `id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `self_id` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;
```

Next add the foreign key constraint:

```
ALTER TABLE `person` ADD CONSTRAINT `self_id_fk` FOREIGN KEY (`self_id`) REFERENCES `person` (`id`);
```

This results in the following table:

```
CREATE TABLE `person` (
  `id` int(11) unsigned NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `self_id` int(11) unsigned DEFAULT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
  KEY `self_id_fk` (`self_id`),
  CONSTRAINT `self_id_fk` FOREIGN KEY (`self_id`) REFERENCES `person` (`id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;
```

Note that an index is automatically created due to the behaviour [described in the documentation](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/create-table-foreign-keys.html)

> ... an index is created on the referencing table automatically if it
>   does not exist

Next I rename the foreign key in the same way as **APPROACH #1**:

```
ALTER TABLE `person`
  DROP FOREIGN KEY `self_id_fk`,
  ADD CONSTRAINT `a_new_fk_name` FOREIGN KEY (`self_id`) REFERENCES `person` (`id`);
```

But this time both the foreign key and the index have been renamed:

```
CREATE TABLE `person` (
  `id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `self_id` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
  KEY `a_new_fk_name` (`self_id`),
  CONSTRAINT `a_new_fk_name` FOREIGN KEY (`self_id`) REFERENCES `person` (`id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;
```

Is there any explanation into what's going on? It's almost as if MySQL is tracking which indexes are "auto created" and then renaming them when the foreign key is changed. The Table DDL is identical for both approaches before the `ALTER TABLE` statement is run so there must be some "internal engine state" that MySQL is tracking.

Looking at the DDL alone there is no way to predict in which way MySQL will behave when the `ALTER TABLE` statement is run. This means that two "schema identical" databases could end up with mismatched schema once a simple `ALTER TABLE` statement has run.

Comment: If you use `ADD FOREIGN KEY` so that MySQL generates the foreign key name (e.g. `table_ibfk_1`) things can get even more confusing - adding a named foreign key later seems to result in the implicit index being renamed to match the new foreign key, even if the previous foreign key still exists!

Answer (score 2):

I have noticed the same thing, but I've never seen any official documentation that explains this.

I agree it seems like InnoDB "knows" which indexes were created implicitly and which were created explicitly. But I don't know where it tracks this information. InnoDB exposes much of the metadata in `INFORMATION_SCHEMA` tables, but it must store more information in the internal data dictionary.

This is the only documentation about the internal DD in MySQL 5.7 and earlier: https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/innodb-data-dictionary.html

The only suggestion I have is that if you need the index name to be predictable, you need to create the index explicitly, then create the foreign key constraint. Don't rely on implicit creation of indexes by foreign keys.

MySQL 8.0 has totally redesigned the data dictionary, so the behavior you observe might change yet again. https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/data-dictionary.html

Comment: You can turn an implicit index into an explicit one by using `ALTER TABLE ADD INDEX`. It doesn't give a "duplicate key name" error if you add an explicit index with the same name and columns as an existing implicit one.